# Is there any way in Laravel to show html and prevent xss attack?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to show HTML which is entered by the user from frontend and same text I have to show in the backend(admin panel) so I am using `{!! !!}` in Laravel to show HTML but recently I observed its not preventing XSS attack so if someone added  this code in text `<script>alert('xss')</script>` than it shows an alert in backend so is there any way in Laravel to show HTML but prevent XSS attack.

Comment: Why do you need to output "raw" HTML in the first place?

Comment: This is actually not an xss attack, but a script injection. You cannot prevent this without stripping all html from the input strings.

Comment: @Thomas I want to show HTML which is entered by the user in the backend

Comment: @Jerodev I know I want to prevent that tag but i am asking is there any inbuild function in laravel to do that

Comment: No, but there are a lot of php functions that can help you with this, like [`strip_tags`](https://www.php.net/strip-tags).

Comment: so is there any list of tags I need to remove from HTML to prevent an attack? @Jerodev

Comment: How about using bbcode for HTML entered by users in combination with strip_tags indeed.

Comment: @Thomas in saving there is no issue I just want to show HTML but make sure XSS attack won't execute.

Comment: Yes but this is a very complex problem, because browsers sometimes even execute malformed javascript if you trick them enough. So it's hard to do it perfectly.

Comment: To prove my point: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: Another way of doing this could be Markdown - combined with some kind of visual editor, this provides a lot of possibilities for editors while maintaining basic security aspects

Comment: @NicoHaase can you give me any example or link?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an html purifier.

Import this package: 
https://github.com/mewebstudio/Purifier

Then you may use

```
clean(Input::get('inputname'));
```

It has an awesome config, tinker it to your liking

publish it with

```
$ php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Mews\Purifier\PurifierServiceProvider"
```

Comment: That's a lot of responsibility to put in a third party library

Comment: Been using it alot, and i see where you are getting from. What do you recommend? since you dont agree with me

Comment: @JasperHelmich Thankyou for your answer but is there any default function in laravel ?

Comment: I would try to solve the root of the problem: Why would you want to output html itself in a variable?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to show the exact same text or HTML entered by user, you don't need to use `{!! !!}` instead you can use `{{ $your_text }}`. It will work exactly the way you want to.

Comment: there is nothing like a single curly brace  ({}) in Laravel blade.. still, I have tried this but it didn't work for me

Comment: I mean {{ $your_text }} .

Comment: Yes , it will escape your html but it will render your HTML like <script>alert('xss')</script> instead of showing alert and I think this is what you want

Comment: Brother read question i want to show HTML as HTML not as text